# iOS CollectionView transitionFromView to swap cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am attempting to swap a CollectionViewCell within a CollectionView using the transitionFromView method inside of a tap gesture. Below is my current implementation.

The animation happens, however I don't believe the new CollectionViewCell is being added to the CollectionView. It "animates" and then shows a blank, white screen. The CollectionView is still functional (ie I can still navigate through it), but my desired functionality is not working.

How can I modify this so that one CollectionViewCell is swapped for a "new" one using this transition method?

The displayingPrimary variable is a Boolean. I am attempting to follow the documentation listed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

```
-(void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

    NSIndexPath* tappedCellPath = [self.myCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[sender locationInView:self.myCollectionView]];

    if(tappedCellPath) {
        UICollectionViewCell *tappedCell = [self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:tappedCellPath];

        UICollectionViewCell *newCell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        newCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [UIView transitionFromView:(displayingPrimary ? tappedCell : newCell)
                            toView:(displayingPrimary ? newCell : tappedCell)
                          duration:1.0
                           options:(displayingPrimary ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight :
                                    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft)
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if (finished) {
                                displayingPrimary = !displayingPrimary;
                            }
                        }];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work like this:

```
     // so first we get the cell that the user has tapped.
     UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     // now we want to do the next thing, which is animate in another cell.
     // so create the other cell (this is a whole cell, not the partial cell we want)
     UITableViewCell *mySecondCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

     // make our new cell the same size as the original cell.
     mySecondCell.frame = myCell.frame;

     // someplace in here we'll add an "Add" string to the cell, white on green.

     mySecondCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

     self.displayingPrimary = YES;

     // sheesh, this works!

     // might have to use core data translation instead, can't find effect I want.
     // this transition seems to affect the whole view (e.g., the entire table).

     [UIView transitionFromView:(self.displayingPrimary ? myCell : mySecondCell)
                 toView:(self.displayingPrimary ? mySecondCell : myCell)
                 duration:1.0 // 0.2 in other guy's example 
                                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft

               completion:^(BOOL finished)
                        {
                  if (finished)
                  {
                    self.displayingPrimary = !self.displayingPrimary;
                  }
                }];
```

Hope this helps!  I'm using the same Apple code example that you are.